# Bootstrap multiselect changes height

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) in my MVC ASP.NET application. I have 3 requirements

- When nothing is selected then dropdownlist should be blank.
- The Caret postion should be on right of the dropdownlist.
- The control should use entire bootstrap grid's column width

I was able to do that. Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1t1nods/1/)

However the issue is whenever I set caret `float:right` or have empty as `nonSelectedText` ( as shown in jsfiddle example) the height of the control changes.
What should I do so control doesn't change the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioned caret instead of floated and set `min-height` for `.multiselect` element.

```
.multiselect {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 34px;
}
.multiselect .caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  line-height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/L1t1nods/3/)